# C#, Windows application, draw a square with side N

Tags: c#, loops

for school practice I have to make a windows application in C# that takes a input number and draws a square of X's with side N. I have to do it with a loops and i can't use any preset commands. (For example math.pow i cannot use) (I've included a picture of the assignment.) I've already mode this program in a console application and there it worked fine. 
I think that i'm very close of solving it but can't figure out what the last step is. I would love to know what i'm missing and how i should solve this.

[See the assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyzMC.png)

This is my code now:

```
            int n;
        n = int.Parse(txt_input.Text);

        //upper part
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
        {
            lbl_output.Text = "X";
            lbl_output.Text = "\n";

        }
        //middel part
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
        {
            lbl_output.Text = "X";
            for (int j = 0; j < n - 2; j++) lbl_output.Text = " ";
            lbl_output.Text = "X";
            lbl_output.Text = "\n";
        }

        //upper part
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
        {
            lbl_output.Text = "X";
            lbl_output.Text = "\n";
        }
```

Comment: Generate the string first. then set the Text property.  Use the += operator.

Comment: You are assigning a new value to the `lbl_output.Text` every time. You need to concatenate with either `lbl_output.Text = lbl_output.Text + "Whatever"` or with `lbl_output.Text += "Whatever"`. Both does the same thing, juste a different way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
int n = int.Parse(txt_input.Text);

//upper part
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    lbl_output.Text += "X";
}

lbl_output.Text += "\n";

//middel part
for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
{
    lbl_output.Text += "X";

    for (int j = 0; j < n - 2; j++)
        lbl_output.Text += "  ";

    lbl_output.Text += "X";
    lbl_output.Text += "\n";
}

//upper part
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    lbl_output.Text += "X";
}
```

You forget to use += which will append the text with the previous assigned text. Also you had some unnecessary new lines in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int n = int.Parse(txt_input.Text);

var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    sb.Append('X');
}
sb.AppendLine();
for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
{
    sb.Append('X');
    for (int j = 0; j < n - 2; j++)
    {
        sb.Append(' ');
    }
    sb.Append('X');
    sb.AppendLine();
}
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    sb.Append('X');
}

lbl_output.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Okay, but the OP is not allowed to use built in functions like `PadRight`. Obviously, he must learn how create his own algorithms and how to use loops etc.

Comment: Sure. I can include a "loop" version in the morning. It's too late now for me to provide an alternative.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - Done.

Answer (score 0):

Need to append to the string. There's a couple ways of doing this. Tho '+=' should work fine. += is short for variable = variable + newValue

```
    int n = int.Parse(txt_input.Text);

    string output = "";

    for(int x = 0; x < n; x++) //rows
    {
        if (x == 0 || x == n-1) //first / last row all x
            for(int y = 0; y < n; y++)
            {
                output += "x";
            }
        else //other rows
            for(int y = 0; y < n; y++) 
            {
                output += (y == 0 || y == n - 1) ? "x" : " "; //if first or last column "X" else " "
            }

        output += "\n"; //at the end of each row a return
    }

    lbl_output.Text = output;
```

You can see it run in the browser here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wiYfjX

Answer (score -1):

Use two loops. One for the width of the square and one for the height of the square.

Give this a try and replace the parameter from what is in the txt_input control. (Just place the function whereever you want in your code (button_click for example) instead of the form load.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblOutput.Text = GenerateSquare(5);
    }

    private string GenerateSquare(int n)
    {
        string square = "";

        for (int w = 0; w < n; w++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < n; h++)
            {
                // top or bottom line
                if (w == 0 || w == n - 1)
                {
                    square += "x";
                }
                else // sides
                {
                    if (h == 0 || h == n - 1)
                    {
                        square += "x";
                    }
                    else square += " ";
                }

                // change line 
                if (h == n - 1)
                    square += "\n";
            }

        }
        return square;
    }
```